# Address not found when contacting java web-app

Tags: spring-webflux, java-17

I've got a simple interface

```
public interface ProductService {
    @GetMapping(value = "/product/{productId}",produces = "application/json")
    String getProduct(@PathVariable int productId);
}
```

implemented by this:

```
@RestController
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Override
    public String getProduct(int productId) {
        return "fake-product";
    }
}
```

this is the pom.xml:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The application starts correctly

[image]

but I only get 404 when trying to contact it:

```
curl http://localhost:7001/product/123
{"timestamp":"2024-01-14T22:52:20.317+00:00","path":"/product/123","status":404,"error":"Not Found","requestId":"a3f586e"}
```

Does it have to do with the fact that I'm using web-flux? It's my first project with it.